# Catching JSON deserialization error on HTTP endpoint

Tags: java, json, servlets, serialization, resteasy

I have a HTTP endpoint that receives and returns JSON content.

While testing for edge cases, I figured the endpoint returns the detailed content of the error when submitting a request with an unexpected JSON object.

In details, I expect a string and instead submit an object, e.g.:

I expect:

```
{
  "myKey" : "someValue" 
}
```

while I submit:

```
{
  "myKey" : {} 
}
```

When submitting that wrong content, what I expect my endpoint to return is:

- a HTTP response with status code 400 and an empty content.

However, what I received was:

- a HTTP response with status code 400 and the following content:

  ```
  Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
  at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@5bcfg1cc; line: 1, column: 11] (through reference chain: com.example.MyRequest["myKey"])
  ```

I am using the RestEasy framework for my servlets and the Jackson library to serialize/deserialize JSON. I have tried to use an ExceptionMapper, to configure exception catching in my web.xml file, but I can apparently cannot catch that error and return an empty HTTP response.

How do I catch errors of JSON deserialization on my HTTP endpoint with RestEasy?

Comment: can u post your method which is consuming json

Answer (score 1):

I am using below mapper and is working

**In place of e.getLocalizedMessage() can use your message**

```
package com.test.rest.service;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;


@Provider
public class DefaultExceptionHandler implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {


    public DefaultExceptionHandler() {
        super();
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
    }



    @Override 
    public Response toResponse(Exception e) {  

        // For simplicity I am preparing error xml by hand.
        // Ideally we should create an ErrorResponse class to hold the error info.
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder("<response>");
        response.append("<status>ERROR</status>");
        response.append("<message>"+e.getLocalizedMessage() + "</message>");
        response.append("<time>" + new Date().toString() + "</time>");
        response.append("</response>");
        return Response.serverError().entity(response.toString()).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).build();
    } 



}
```

My method :

```
@GET
@Path("consumeJSON")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String consumeJSON(Map<String, String> outputMap) { 
    return outputMap.get("Hello");

}
```

Comment: Thanks you saved me a whole lot of headache trying to figure out how to intercept the 500 error that the servlet would return instead of the custom error message I'd like to return